# The Ship Source Dedicated Server not starting

Tags: technical-issues, linux, hosting, the-ship

I am trying to run a srcds for The Ship game from Linux (Debian v8).  It is downloaded and all the files seem to be there, but whenever I try to run `~/servers/ship/srcds_run -game ~/servers/ship/ship +map andrea_doria +max_players 10` I get an error saying

> Auto detecting CPU
>
> Using AMD Optimised binary.
>
> Auto-restarting the server on crash
>
> Unable to find gameinfo.txt. Solutions:
>
> 1. Read http://www.valve-erc.com/srcsdk/faq.html#NoGameDir
> 2. Run vconfig to specify which game you're working on.
> 3. Add -game  on the command line where  is the directory that gameinfo.txt is in.
>
> Unable to find gameinfo.txt. Solutions:
>
> 1. Read http://www.valve-erc.com/srcsdk/faq.html#NoGameDir
> 2. Run vconfig to specify which game you're working on.
> 3. Add -game  on the command line where  is the directory that gameinfo.txt is in.
>      Add "-debug" to the /home/steam/servers/ship/srcds_run command line to generate a debug.log to help with solving this problem
>
> Thu Oct 15 07:21:58 CDT 2015: Server restart in 10 seconds

I went to the `http://www.valve-erc.com/srcsdk/faq.html#NoGameDir`*(note1)* but that isn't a website, I tried to run `vconfig` but I couldn't find a file named that, and to be sure I had the right path I first ran `cd /home/steam/servers/ship/` then ran `./srcds_run -game ./ship +map andrea_doria +max_players 10` and it came back with the same error.  I then tried `/home/steam/servers/ship/srcds_run -game /home/steam/servers/ship/ship +map andrea_doria +max_players 10` but same error.  Now I tried to add `-debug` but after it runs I can't find `debug.log` anywhere.

I know this is not an srcds issue because I can run a CS:GO server fine using `~/servers/csgo/srcds_run -game csgo -console +net_public_adr {My IP} +game_type 1 +game_mode 2 +map de_shorttrain -authkey {My AuthKey} +exec start/start`.

This is not the same as [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174477/hosting-a-linux-dedicated-server-for-the-ship) because he can actually get it running, though it is freezing, it runs.  Mine won't start at all and won't accept any commands.

*(note1)* - I used the [WayBackMachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20080504101814/http://www.valve-erc.com/srcsdk/faq.html#faqGameDir) to try to find information with the valve-erc website but I cannot find a part of the code of the site (at any point of time) that said `name="NoGameDir"` so there is no information on this site anyway, even if it is still up.

Comment: also note: I can run the windows version with no issues

Comment: Try running "~/servers/ship/srcds_run -console -game ship +map andrea_doria +max_players 10"

Comment: @Adam it just replies `Invalid game type 'ship' sepecified.`

Comment: Then try the same thing but use your original game path for `-game`. Leave `-console` in still.

Comment: @adam the `-console` command isn't making a difference with any way i set the directories, it seems to not accept any commands like `-console` or `-debug`

Comment: Are you using the path to the game's .exe instead of the gameinfo.txt file?

Comment: @adam no, the gameinfo.txt is `/home/steam/servers/ship/ship/gameinfo.txt` so i have the command reference `/home/steam/servers/ship/ship/`, and the `.exe` (linux does not use exe but it would be in the same location) is `/home/steam/servers/ship/srcds_run` and when starting the command i directly reference that file.  Also when i do `ls /home/steam/servers/ship/ship/` the GameInfo.txt appears along with a bunch of other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it out.  Turns out that linux is very case sensitive.  The server is looking for `gameinfo.txt` when the file is called `GameInfo.txt` by default, I just renamed the file and it's starting fine.